# how to execute a script that will modify my package at build time?

Tags: python, setuptools

We have the following package structure:

```
.
├── genreate_source/
│   ├── generate_schema.py
│   ├── generate_source.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── ipyvuetify/
│   ├── template.py
│   ├── Html.py
│   ├── Themes.py
│   ├── Template.py
│   └── _init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.py
```

the main package is ipyvuetify but the content is generated from the vuetify.js API. To buid the source, we need to execute a function that live in `generate_source.py`. Until now we were adding these source at release time but that makes developping in the lib complicated. We try to make the build automatic and included in the `python build`.

When we try to importe "genreate_source" module in the setup.py it doesn't work (moduleNotFound). Is it normal and can we call this script from septup ?

Comment: It is probably not in the same directory or if its path is not added to your sys.path

Comment: Huh... this code generation is not specific to the installation target is it (it does not depend on the operating system, Python interpreter version, CPU bitness)? If it is not specific to the installation target then the code generation should happen before the construction of the *sdist* (and obviously before the *wheel* as well). So, that would leave `setup.py` and *setuptools* and `python -m build` out of the game. From my point of view, at least.

Comment: no it's not platform specific. What you describe is the current implementation, We try to simplify it from a user point of view

Comment: Users typically do `pip install` of a *sdist* or a *wheel* (hosted on a package index server). So if the *sdist* already contains the files with generated code, there is nothing specific to write in `setup.py`. -- I recommend to leave code generation out of `setup.py`, unless the code generation is specific to the platform or environment.

Comment: I see your point, but your solution complexify the development process as maintainers need to remember to build all the assets when doing a release (or create a CI that does it for you) why not doing it with setup.py when building the wheel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the beggining of the setup.py file, You need to add the parent directory to sys so that the included files become callable.

Here is  the skeleton of a build  command that will create extra file:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from pynpm import NPMPackage
from setuptools import Command, setup
from setuptools.command.egg_info import egg_info

ROOT = Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.append(str(ROOT))

from generate_source import generate_source  # noqa


def js_prerelease(command: Command) -> None:
    """Decorator for building minified js/css prior to another command"""

    class DecoratedCommand(command):
        """Decorated command to install jsdeps first."""

        def run(self):
            """Run the command"""
            NPMPackage(ROOT / "js" / "package.json").install()
            generate_source.generate()
            self.distribution.data_files = get_data_files()
            command.run(self)

    return DecoratedCommand


setup(cmdclass={"egg_info": js_prerelease(egg_info)})
```